# How to skip a build step based on environment variable in Buldkite pipeline.yml file?

Tags: continuous-integration, buildkite

I have a pipeline.yml for buildkite CI which is:

```
steps:
  - label: "Test"
    command: test.sh
    skip: "$BUILDKITE_BRANCH == 'mybranch'"
```

I want to skip the build step if the branch name is `mybranch` but this setting doesn't seem to work in buildkite. This step is still run. I wonder how I can use environment variable in `skip` condition. I know I can check the environment inside `test.sh` script but I don't really want to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`skip` will cause the step to skipped if it has any value. The value is intended to indicate why the step was skipped, and is not evaluated as a boolean.

There is a built-in way to skip steps for specific branches using [branch configuration](https://buildkite.com/docs/pipelines/branch-configuration#step-level-branch-filtering) instead:

```
steps:
  - label: "Test"
    command: test.sh
    branches: "!mybranch"
```

There is also a recently introduced way to use more complex rules called [conditionals](https://buildkite.com/docs/pipelines/conditionals), although it might be more than is required here:

```
steps:
  - label: "Test"
    command: test.sh
    if: build.branch != "mybranch"
```

Comment: Right, but it doesn't support all my environment variables. I am looking for using a customised variable on the if condition.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that context wasn't in the question. `build.env("BUILDKITE_BRANCH")` works for example, but custom env isn't yet supported. Perhaps email support@buildkite.com with your specific case and maybe we can solve it for you?